# Windows 10 'fixed' files created in Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, data-corruption

I have a dual-boot system with Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10. Today when I launched Windows 10 it started "Checking and repairing" the hard drive, found several "corrupt files" and "fixed" them. Has Windows deleted those files and folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, Linux (Ubuntu) supports read and write support of partitions formatted with the NTFS file system, the file system used by Windows. If the file system is healthy, it should not be a problem working with NTFS under Linux. However, to ensure that the file system remains healthy:

- When shutting down Windows, shut it down completely, i.e no "fast-boot" or no hibernation. This way, MS Windows completely closes the partition and leaves it in a clean state to whatever OS accesses it on next boot.
- When using the NTFS partition in Linux, make sure you shut down Linux fully and completely, again to ensure the partition is correctly closed.
- Importantly, regularly connect the partition to MS Windows and have the drive checked there. Because NTFS is a proprietary file system format, only the Windows tools know it the full ins and outs. For this reason, one should use the NTFS file system only if it periodically can be connected the file system to a Windows system (as in your case).

Thus, some extra care is needed, but it should not be a problem to share an NTFS partition for having data available under both Windows and Linux.

In your case, some corruption has happened. Head the advise above to prevent that from happening again. For now, your partition has already been checked and repaired under Windows. I would check it once more with the Windows disk checking tool to make sure. It should not happen again if each time you carefully close the operating system and have the disk checked manually now and then in Windows.

> "Has Windows deleted those files and folders?"

Windows was unable to recognize file names and connect these to the file contents stored on disk. The folders have been deleted. The contents of the files have been recovered in files with a random name, stored in a folder `\found.000`. Some of these files, but not necessarily all, may still "work". If there is important stuff there for which you do not have a backup, then you will need to try to recognize which file is which, and rename them accordingly.